# VisualStudio - Deploy Error

Tags: apex, visualforce

I'm having 2 errors when i try to deploy my code in my org:

> Variable does not exist: PriceMargin__c[43:27]
> Variable does not exist: Price__c[44:27]

The full code is here:

```
public with sharing class OrderItemHelper {
public OrderItemHelper() {}

public static void checkError(List<OrderItem> OrderItemList) {
    for (OrderItem orderItem : orderItemList) {
        if (orderItem.Quantity <= 0) {
            orderItem.addError(Label.OrderItemQuantityError);
        }
        else if (orderItem.UnitPrice <= 0) {
            orderItem.addError(Label.OrderItemPriceError);
        }
    }
}

public static void calcPrice(List<OrderItem> orderItemList) {
    Set<Id> orderIdSet = new Set<Id>();
    Set<Id> productIdSet = new Set<Id>();

    for (OrderItem orderItem : orderItemList) {
        orderIdSet.add(orderItem.OrderId);
        productIdSet.add(orderItem.Product2Id);
    }

    Map<Id, Order> orderMap = new Map<Id, Order>([
        SELECT Id, AccountId, Account.AccountGroup__c, DistributionCenter__c, DistributionCenter__r.State__c
        FROM Order
        WHERE Id IN: orderIdSet
    ]);

    Map<Id, Product2> productMap = new Map<Id, Product2>([
        SELECT Id, ProductHierarchy__c
        FROM Product2
        WHERE Id IN: productIdSet
    ]);

    // search margins
    Map<OrderItem, PriceMargin__c> orderItemToMargin = searchMargin(orderItemList, orderMap, productMap);

    for (OrderItem orderItem : orderItemToMargin.keySet()) {
        PriceMargin__c priceMargin = orderItemToMargin.get(orderItem);

        if (priceMargin != null) {
            orderItem.PriceMargin__c = PriceMargin.Id;
            orderItem.Price__c = orderItem.ListPrice - (orderItem.ListPrice * (priceMargin.Margin__c/100));
        }
    }
}

public static Map<OrderItem, PriceMargin__c> SearchMargin(List<OrderItem> orderItemList, Map<Id, Order> orderMap, Map<Id, Product2> ProductMap) {
    Set<Id> ProductIds      = new Set<Id>();
    Set<Id> hierarchyIds    = new Set<Id>();
    Set<Id> accountIds      = new Set<Id>();
    Set<Id> groupIds        = new Set<Id>();
    Set<Id> distributionIds = new Set<Id>();
    Set<Id> stateIds        = new Set<Id>();

    for (Order order : orderMap.values()) {
        accountIds.add(order.AccountId);
        groupIds.add(order.Account.AccountGroup__c);
        distributionids.add(order.DistributionCenter__c);
        stateIds.add(order.DistributionCenter__r.State__c);
    }

    for (Product2 product : productMap.values()) {
        ProductIds.add(product.Id);
        hierarchyIds.add(product.ProductHierarchy__c);
    }

    List<PriceMargin__c> priceMarginList = [
        SELECT Id, Product__c, ProductHierarchy__c, Account__c, AccountGroup__c, DistributionCenter__c, State__c, Margin__c, Score__c
        FROM PriceMargin__c
        WHERE (Product__c IN: productIds OR Product__c = null) AND
        (ProductHierarchy__c IN: hierarchyIds OR ProductHierarchy__c = null) AND
        (Account__c IN: accountIds OR Account__c = null) AND
        (AccountGroup__c IN: groupIds OR AccountGroup__c = null) AND
        (DistributionCenter__c IN: distributionIds OR DistributionCenter__c = null) AND
        (State__c IN: stateIds OR State__c = null)
        ORDER BY Score__c
    ];

    Map<OrderItem, PriceMargin__c> orderItemToMargin = new Map<OrderItem, PriceMargin__c>();

    for (OrderItem orderItem : orderItemList) {
        orderItemToMargin.put(orderItem, null);

        for (PriceMargin__c margin : priceMarginList) {
            if (matchMargin(margin, orderItem, orderMap, productMap)) {
                orderItemToMargin.put(orderItem, margin);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return orderItemToMargin;
}

public static Boolean matchMargin(PriceMargin__c margin, OrderItem orderItem, Map<Id, Order> orderMap, Map<Id, Product2> ProductMap) {
   return (String.isBlank(margin.Product__c) || margin.Product__c == orderItem.Product2Id) &&
   (String.isBlank(margin.ProductHierarchy__c) || margin.ProductHierarchy__c == productMap.get(orderItem.Product2Id).ProductHierarchy__c) &&
   (String.isBlank(margin.Account__c) || margin.Account__c == orderMap.get(orderItem.OrderId).AccountId) &&
   (String.isBlank(margin.AccountGroup__c) || margin.AccountGroup__c == orderMap.get(orderItem.OrderId).Account.AccountGroup__c) &&
   (String.isBlank(margin.DistributionCenter__c) || margin.DistributionCenter__c == orderMap.get(orderItem.OrderId).DistributionCenter__c) &&
   (String.isBlank(margin.State__c) || margin.State__c == orderMap.get(orderItem.OrderId).DistributionCenter__r.State__c);
}
```

}

What am i doing wrong here? Tried to search everywhere in the code, but couldn't find the problem :(

Comment: Does your profile have access to these custom fields? Do these fields exist on OrderItem object? Also check if you or someone has accidentally created a class named OrderItem in you org.

Comment: Well, do the objects PriceMargin__c & Price__c exist in the environment you are deploying to?